# union of two spaces

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

I would like to prove that the union of two subspaces is equal to a subspace.

note $X$ a measurable space and $f,g,h : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are mesurable functions with also $r ,t >0$

I would like to prove that $E_1 = \{x \in X | |f-g| \geq r \}  $ and $ E_2 = \{ x \in X | |g-h| \geq t  \}$
gives
$E_1 \cup E_2 = \{ x \in X | |f-h| \geq r +t \}$

I don't know as to how I should proceed to prove the following

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \notin E_1$ and $x \notin E_2$, then $|f(x) - h(x)| \le |f(x) - g(x)| + |g(x) + h(x)| < r + t$, so $x \notin \{y \in X \mid |f(y) - h(y) \ge r+t\}$. This proves
$$E_1^c \cap E_2^c \subseteq \{x \in X \mid |f(x) - h(x) \ge r+t\}^c$$
which is equivalent to
$$E_1 \cup E_2 \supseteq \{x \in X \mid |f(x) - h(x) \ge r+t\}.$$

I don't think the reverse inclusion holds.
Let $f \equiv 1$, $g \equiv 0$, and $h \equiv 1$, and let $r=t=1/2$. Then $E_1=E_2 = X$, but $\{x \in X \mid |f(x) - h(x)| \ge 1\} = \varnothing$.

Comment: i'm sorry but what does $E^c$ mean? is it the complement?

Comment: @a_confused_student Yes, the complement